# Laravel cart page product quantity update with ajax problem

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I want to update my cart page product quantity with ajax but not working. My cartController is not getting any response. I went to the browser network option and saw that Ajax has sent its data but I am not getting any response from the server

View file:

```
@foreach ($cartProduct as $cartsProduct)
    <tr class="cartPage">
        <td class="shoping__cart__item">
            <img src="{{asset('upload/'.$cartsProduct->products->product_future_image)}}" alt="">
            <h5>{{$cartsProduct->products->product_name}}</h5>
        </td>
        <td class="shoping__cart__price">
            ${{$cartsProduct->product_price}}
        </td>
        <td class="shoping__cart__quantity">
            <div class="quantity">
                <input type="hidden" name="CartID" class="productID" value="{{$cartsProduct>id}}">
                <div class="pro-qty">
                    <input type="text" class="productQty" name="CartQuantity" value="{{$cartsProduct->product_quantity}}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="shoping__cart__total">
            ${{$cartsProduct->product_quantity * $cartsProduct->product_price}}
        </td>
        <td class="shoping__cart__item__close">
            <a href="{{url('cart-product-delete', $cartsProduct->id)}}"><span class="icon_close"></span></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.updateQuantiy').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var cartID = $(this).closest('.cartPage').find('.productID').val();
        var productQuantity = $(this).closest('.cartPage').find('.productQty').val();

        var data = {
            '_token' : "{{csrf_token()}}",
            'cartID' : cartID,
            'productQuantity' : productQuantity,
        };

        $.ajax({
            url : '/cart-quantity-update',
            type : 'POST',
            data : data,
            success: function(response){
                window.location.reload();
                toastr.options = {"closeButton": true, "progressBar": true }
                toastr.success(response.status);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/cart-quantity-update', [CartController::class, 'updateQuantity']);
```

cartController:

```
    public function updateQuantity(Request $request){
        $CartID = $request->post('CartID');
        $cartQuantity = $request->post('CartQuantity');

        $cartUpdate = Cart::where('id', $CartID)->where('user_ip', request()->ip());
        $cartUpdate->product_quantity = $cartQuantity;
        $cartUpdate->save();

        return response()->json(['status' => 'Product Quantity Updated']);
    }
```

```
I want to update cart quantity from here.
```

Comment: You're using ajax then immediately reloading the page?

Comment: remove window.location.reload(); from ajax success

Comment: Remove but it still doesn't work @ANASMK